# Build and install Boost 1.60 in 32 bit on a 64 bit Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: c++, macos, boost, x86

I have an application that use the 32 bit boost library( 1.48 ). The 1.48 version of boost was pre built on 32 bit platform and uses older C++ standards.
For example `file libboost_wserialization.dylib` gives
`libboost_wserialization.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
libboost_wserialization.dylib (for architecture i386):  Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
libboost_wserialization.dylib (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64`

The requirements have changed and i want to link/use the boost 1.60 with C++ 11 and 32 bit. 
I have downloaded the 1.60 boost and modified the `bootstrap.sh` to include application specific lib and include directories.

I am running the following command

`./b2 cxxflags="-std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++"  address-model=32 architecture=x86 install`

I get the following error 
`error: unknown target CPU 'i686'` for all the files.
If i install the default then I don get the 32 bit version of the boost libraries and application fails to link.

How do i get rid of this error ?. The machine that i am building boost on is Mac OS X El capitan 64 bit.

The entire error is

```
 "clang++" -x c++ -std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++ -O3 -O3 -Wno-inline -Wall -march=i686 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_MATH_TR1_DYN_LINK=1 -DNDEBUG -I"." -I"libs/math/src/tr1" -c -o "bin.v2/libs/math/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/release/address-model-32/threading-multi/atanh.o" "libs/math/build/../src/tr1/atanh.cpp"
```

`...failed clang-darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/math/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/release/address-model-32/threading-multi/atanh.o...
clang-darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/math/build/clang-darwin-4.2.1/release/address-model-32/threading-multi/cbrt.o
error: unknown target CPU 'i686'`

Answer (score 0):

Try with address-model=64.

More info: http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/reference/tools.html#bbv2.reference.tools.compiler.darwin

Comment: No. It still builds only 32 bit i guess, linking of my application still fails. `libboost_wserialization.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64`

Comment: The issue got fixed by using an older version of XCode. I was using the XCode 6.4. I used another machine with XCode 5.4 and was able to build a dylib with i386 arch.